# How do I find Laurent Serie for $\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$

Tags: power-series, laurent-series

Find Laurent Serie in all three ranges.

What I did:

$\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z-2}$

$\frac{1}{z-1}= -\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n, |z|<1$

$\frac{1}{z-1}= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{-n}, |z|>1$

$\frac{1}{z-2}= -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z}{2})^n, |z|<2$

$\frac{1}{z-2}= \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{z})^n, |z|>2$

My questions:

1. What should I do with first part of function $\frac{1}{z}$?
2. How to combine these in three ranges?

Comment: Just for the last one : $\frac{1}{z-2}, |z| > 2$, I think there should be a $\frac{1}{z}$ in front of the sum and not $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you're to find the laurent series around $z=0$, then it's as simple as:

$${1\over z} = z^{-1}$$

that is just one term for $1/z$ (for $|z|>0$).

As for combining them, you just add them together termwise. You will have the ranges $0<|z|<1$, $1<|z|<2$ and $|z|>2$ and select the variants that are applicable for respective range.

For example for the range $0<|z|<1$ you have $\sum c_nz^n$ where:

$$c_n = \begin{cases}
- 1 - 2^{-n}/4 & \text{ if } n\ge 0 & \text{ because of }1/(z-1)\text{ and } 1/2(z-2) \\
1/2 & \text{ if } n=-1 &\text{ because of }1/2z\\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I dont understand how did you get all these parts? Can I for first range add sum of $1/z$ and $|z|<1$? For second range, sum of $|z|>1$ and $|z<2|$ and so on..?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic I add the Laurent series for $1/2z$ for the range $|z|>0$, the Laurent series for $1/(z-1)$ for the range $|z|<1$ and the Laurent series for $1/2(z-2)$ for the range $|z|<2$. All those Laurent series are valid for the range $0<|z|<1$. Then for the second range you will need to use the Laurent series of $1/(z-1)$ for the range $1<|z|$ and in the last range you will have to change the Laurent series for $1/2(z-2)$ as well.